# Stop Angular Click event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi i retrying to restrict the navigation & tab controls in existing application while having changes in data before save. The application is already developed in AngularJS. So i have returned the JQuery code for global level for restriction using the classes.

This is My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".mandatory-data").change(function (e) {
       if (e.originalEvent) {
           $(this).addClass('mandatory-data-entered');
       } else {
           $(this).removeClass('mandatory-data-entered');
       }
   });

   $(".check-mandatory-data").click(function (event) {        
       if ($(".mandatory-data-entered").length > 0) {
           alert("Not Allow");  
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();          
           return false;
       }
   });
});
```

Now the my functions is working fine. But the problem is angular functions and href is not stopped after my alter message the other functions working.

My Code is

```
<a href="#" class="check-mandatory-data" ng-click="dataClickEvent();">Data</a>
```

Here Both events are working check-mandatory-data event and dataClickEvent(). How to restrict the dataClickEvent() using the condition $(".check-mandatory-data").click() event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you do this in the `ng-click` itself by passing event object `$event`.

Comment: if you want to restrict then remove `ng-click="dataClickEvent();"`?

Comment: @Jai my existing application is having near by 85 Screens  so it contains more number of controllers and more events. is it not possible to change in all the place that's what i am writing in global level code

Comment: @Alive to Die if condition is failed ng-click event has to work or else i need to restrict it. So i need to restrict it in jquery itself

Comment: friends kindly give me any idea to achieve this task

Comment: you can use :  $(".check-mandatory-data").undelegate( 'click');

Comment: @Jenny i have already tried its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure if that works, but you could try using .mousedown() instead of .click().

Inside .mousedown() you could $(this).removeAttr('ng-click'). Maybe store its value and reapply it on a .mouseup().

Comment: Ya its not working i have tried in focusin event While loading time it self ng-click is assigned the event to particular control

Comment: removeAttr is working after the attr added the ng-click but its not hitting the function